# What is "X Software Development" equivalent on ubuntu?

Tags: apt, development, tools

When I try to "groupinstall" this package:

`sudo apt -y groupinstall "X Software Development"`

I have 2 problems, first `groupinstall` doesn't exists on ubuntu, second, Ubuntu can't locate the package.

Comment: Could you please translate "groupinstall" to package names? What do you need - X11 or what? What are you trying to compile or run? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: hc40523 : »can't locate the package« : May be "locate a file" will help? https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=Xmu.h&searchon=contents ........ and `sudo apt install apt-file` → → `apt-file search [file]`

Comment: @N0rbert I just learned around while posting what groupinstall meant

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for the hint, yes I tried before asking. As this "grouped packages" was for yum packages manager it returned nothing

Comment: `sudo apt install libxmu-dev` will install a package that has the most "X-dev" packages as dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to bring knowledge about Yum's functionality to Debian (really Ubuntu).

On Ubuntu you have to install `xorg-dev` and/or `xserver-xorg-dev` [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xorg-dev&searchon=names) to get "X.Org X Window System development libraries" and/or "Xorg X server - development files" installed by using below commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev xserver-xorg-dev
```

Then you can try to compile needed application from source. But at first make sure that it is not available in binary package form. Use search on https://packages.ubuntu.com and then install needed package(s) by `apt`/`apt-get`.

If you need different X11-related thing - visit special x11 packages section at https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/x11/ to find relevant package name.

---

Good resources to read:

- https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/package-management
- `man apt` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt.8.html)
- `man apt-get` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)
- `man aptitude` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/aptitude-curses.8.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, as I wasn't even able to understand why I need it! The fact is since I switched to Ubuntu my code won't compile, it was on fedora, using my teacher libraries of "TThread" and "screen" etc.. told us to install X Software packages and also tck, tck-devel, tcl, tcl-devel.. still have to figure out those. But for instance I'll try to see if I get succcessful build with your help, or at least less errors. Thank you!

Comment: tcl / tk https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=tk8 ..... Install e.g. `tk8.6-dev`, and tcl packages will be installed too : as dependencies.